# some strange fields was added after converting protobuf message to go struct?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I want to have an API to save a User. Here is my user message:

```
message User {
    int32 uid = 1;
    string username = 2;
    string password = 3;
}
```

And I use `protoc-gen-go` to convert it to go struct. I found some strange fields was added(`XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral`, `XXX_unrecognized`).

```
type User struct {
    Uid                  int32    `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=uid,proto3" json:"uid,omitempty"`
    Username             string   `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=username,proto3" json:"username,omitempty"`
    Password             string   `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=password,proto3" json:"password,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}
```

I can't save it to MySQL due to those fields because my MySQL table doesn't have those fields. anyone good advice? I have to create another struct to convert MySQL table to protobuf Message?

Comment: There is an open GitHub issue related to it, a lot of people don't like it. https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/276
For now you can create your own struct for DB, excluding XXX properties.

Comment: @pltvs alright.

Answer (score 0):

[gogoprotobuf](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf) is a fork of golang/protobuf with extra code generation features.

protoc-gen-gogofaster (without XXX_unrecognized, less pointer fields)

```
go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gofaster

go install github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gofaster

protoc --gofaster_out=plugins=grpc:. my.proto
```